# Getting Airport network password using SecKeychainFindGenericPassword

Tags: objective-c, macos, wifi, keychain

I'm trying to get Airport network password using This api SecKeychainFindGenericPassword().
But I always get itemnotfound error . I'm not sure what to pass in Account name and service name in the API . I added code snippet to show what I m doing. Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks

```
 OSStatus status1 ;

SecKeychainRef kychain = nil;
SecKeychainCopyDefault(&kychain);
status1 = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword (
                                          kychain,           // default keychain
                                          15,             // length of service name
                                          "AirPort Network",   // service name
                                          38,             // length of account name
                                          "com.apple.network.wlan.ssid.xxxxxxxx",   // account name
                                          passwordLength,  // length of password
                                          &passwordData,   // pointer to password data
                                          itemRef          // the item reference
                                          );
return (status1);
```

I'm using osx 10.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the service and account swapped.  The service should be the SSID, and the account name should be "AirPort".

```
SecKeychainRef keychain;
OSStatus err = SecKeychainOpen("/Library/Keychains/System.keychain", &keychain);

#define kServiceName "com.apple.network.wlan.ssid.Rackus"
#define kAccountName "AirPort"

UInt32 passwordLength = 0;
char* passwordData = nil;
UInt32 serviceNameLength = strlen(kServiceName);
UInt32 accountNameLength = strlen(kAccountName);
SecKeychainItemRef itemRef;

err = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(keychain, serviceNameLength, kServiceName, accountNameLength, kAccountName, &passwordLength, (void**)&passwordData, &itemRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Service Name is the name of the service you want to get the password and account name is user's account name(you can get it by calling NSUserName(), but beware, this returns a NSString* and this API is written in C, so it expects a const char*).

As I said, since the KeyChain API is written in C, I highly recommend you to use a wrapper library to do the work, if you're not confortable with plain C. I would suggest you this one:
https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain